# Convert HTML code into jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a code in HTML using `Spring` notation.
The code is:

```
<c:if test="${testCSV==true}">
<a href="#" onclick="editCSV(${command.id})" rel="tooltip-top"><img src="images/icons/edit.png" width="25"  height="25" /></a>
</c:if>
```

I want to check this condition in `jQuery`, So the condition checks dynamically.
please help me.

Comment: And where comes the testCSV value from?

Comment: Question isn't clear enough. Please include some more details, about what are the elements you used, what you want to do.

Comment: testCSV value comes from spring controller. if it is true, then in my edit page icon shows, but when i update page then does not show the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in html where you want to edit button to show

```
<a id="edit" href="#" onclick="editCSV(${command.id})" rel="tooltip-top">
    <img src = "images/icons/edit.png" width = "25" height = "25" /> 
</a>
```

**js**

```
if (test == true) {
    $('#edit').show();
} else {
    $('#edit').hide();
}
```

pass true

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test =pagetype('<%=${testCSV}%>');
    if (test == true) {
        $('#edit').show();
    } else {
        $('#edit').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how the true value will come, for test.

Comment: pass true in the var true through JSP CODE

Comment: I wrote var test=${testCSV}; , but it not works. Icons seen always whenther it is true or not?

Comment: `text = pagetype('<%=${testCSV}%>');` try

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = ${testCSV};
    // some other code
</script>
```

The browser will see it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = true; // or false
    // some other code
</script>
```

Then, do whatever you like with it.